# Organogram- All nodes should be open when a parent is clicked second time

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm working on jquery orgchart, based on https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/option-createNode.html. WHen i click on parent node all the children and siblings everything get closed. But when i again click on the parent only the first level childern is opening and remaining nodes are closed. Is there any way while clicking on the parent node second time it should open all the nodes?

Can any one please help me to solve the issue

Please find below the code which i am working on currently.

```js
$(function() {

  var datascource = {
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Lao Lao',
    'title': 'general manager',
    'children': [{
        'id': '2',
        'name': 'Bo Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'id': '3',
        'name': 'Su Miao',
        'title': 'department manager',
        'children': [{
            'id': '4',
            'name': 'Tie Hua',
            'title': 'senior engineer'
          },
          {
            'id': '5',
            'name': 'Hei Hei',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'children': [{
                'id': '6',
                'name': 'Pang Pang',
                'title': 'engineer'
              },
              {
                'id': '7',
                'name': 'Xiang Xiang',
                'title': 'UE engineer'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'id': '8',
        'name': 'Yu Jie',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'id': '9',
        'name': 'Yu Li',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'id': '10',
        'name': 'Hong Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'id': '11',
        'name': 'Yu Wei',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'id': '12',
        'name': 'Chun Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
      },
      {
        'id': '13',
        'name': 'Yu Tie',
        'title': 'department manager'
      }
    ]
  };

  $('#chart-container').orgchart({
    'data': datascource,
    'visibleLevel': 2,
    'nodeContent': 'title',
    'nodeID': 'id',
    'createNode': function($node, data) {      
      var secondMenuIcon = $('<i>', {
        'class': 'fa fa-info-circle second-menu-icon',
        click: function(event) {                                           
          if($(this).siblings('.second-menu').is( ":visible" )){          
           $(this).siblings('.second-menu').hide();                  
          }else{
           $('.second-menu').hide();                    
            $(this).siblings('.second-menu').show();                  
          }                      
          event.stopPropagation();                   
        }
      });     
      var secondMenu =  '<div class="second-menu"><img class="avatar" src="img/avatar/' + data.id + '.jpg"></div>';
      $node.append(secondMenuIcon).append(secondMenu);     
    }
  });

});

$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  $('.second-menu').hide();
});
```

```css
.orgchart .second-menu-icon {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: rgba(68, 157, 68, 0.5);
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
}

.orgchart .second-menu-icon:hover {
  color: #449d44;
}

.orgchart .node:hover .second-menu-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.orgchart .node .second-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -70px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #999;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.orgchart .node .second-menu .avatar {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
```

Jsfiddle

Comment: Can anyone please guide me how to achive the above problem?

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.